# spark streaming kafka convert string to JSON

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading sensor data through an MQTT broker to a kafka pipleline and want to process the data using spark structured streaming.

I have tested the following and I'm able to get the data into spark (so far so good).

```
// create conf and streaming context: 
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn").setAppName("sensor_example")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))

val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.2.109:9092").option("subscribe", "test_message").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()

// cast the value from binary to string: 
val sensorDf = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
val sensorOutput = sensorDf.as[String]   // do I need this?

    // write to the command line: 
sensorOutput.writeStream.format("console").option("truncate","false").start().awaitTermination()
```

The output of the code above is:

```
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{
   "temperature": "28", 
   "message_no": "4727", 
   "timestamp": "2019-06-02 12:59:02.526809", 
   "average": "28.6454410831", 
   "humidity": "38", 
   "fahrenheit": "82"
}|
|{
   "temperature": "28", 
   "message_no": "4728", 
   "timestamp": "2019-06-02 12:59:08.276594", 
   "average": "28.6453045685", 
   "humidity": "38", 
   "fahrenheit": "82"
}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to convert this to a dataframe with the respective column structure. 
The object created is either a DataFrame or a DataSet (with one column).

```
scala> val sensorDf = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
sensorDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> val sensorOutput = sensorDf.as[String]
sensorOutput: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> sensorOutput.printSchema
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

However, I cannot find a way how to convert this into a DataFrame with the columns and values defined by the fields of the string. 
The schema should be the following:

```
// create the schema: 
val sensorSchema = StructType(Array(
 StructField("temperature", IntegerType),
 StructField("message_no", IntegerType),
 StructField("timestamp", StringType),
 StructField("average", DoubleType),
 StructField("humidity", IntegerType),
 StructField("fahrenheit", IntegerType)
))
```

I already tried:

```
scala> val dataDf = sensorDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as json").select(from_json($"json", schema=sensorSchema).as("data")).select("data.*")
dataDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [temperature: int, message_no: int ... 4 more fields]

scala> dataDf.printSchema()
root
 |-- temperature: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- message_no: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- average: double (nullable = true)
 |-- humidity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- fahrenheit: integer (nullable = true)
```

But the output is:

```
scala> dataDf.writeStream.format("console").option("truncate","false").start().awaitTermination()
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-----------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+
|temperature|message_no|timestamp|average|humidity|fahrenheit|
+-----------+----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+
|null       |null      |null     |null   |null    |null      |
|null       |null      |null     |null   |null    |null      |
|null       |null      |null     |null   |null    |null      |
|null       |null      |null     |null   |null    |null      |
|null       |null      |null     |null   |null    |null      |
|null       |null      |null     |null   |null    |null      |
|null       |null      |null     |null   |null    |null      |


Thanks for any suggestion.
```

Comment: What you did looks correct (you get all columns), but each field in your JSON is just a String, so try just using StringType only to start

Comment: I'm currently checking whether the input is only a string and not a real JSON. Even it looks like JSON it is considered as string

Comment: Only when you `CAST`, which is required to take bytes to a string. But not after you do `from_json`... You just need to figure out why that piece isn't working, and the problem could be your schema does not match your JSON values since they are all strings

Comment: Notice: The data in that question is also all quoted. When they try double and long types, its null. When (correctly) using StringType, the data is all returned.